# Fiddler possible error maybe with LAN

Tags: proxy, lan, http, fiddler

Ok the problem begin when i begin using fiddler it was really usefull for facebook games, etc.
But one day when I started the computer the internet conection was not working, so after many tries i I opened internet "Tools" and then "Internet Options" then "Connections" and finally "LAN Settings

there in "LAN Settings" I disabled "Use a proxy server for your LAN..." i accepted and i get out. The internet was working again but fiddler was not.

ANY idea??

I already tried restarting the computer, reinstalling fiddler and using internet as an administrator changing the proxy server 
notes:
I have IE 9
I use fiddler version 2.3.9.0